# Search function using listview in vb

Tags: database, vb.net

i get a change of data in a first column in a listview after search a data.
Example:
in a first column, the data must display a room code like "3234" but after do a searching the data change to "Room_Code". 
Below is the code for search function

```
Private Sub Search()

    ListViewRoom.Items.Clear()

    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    Dim _isFound As Boolean = False

    Dim colName() As String = {"Room_Code", "Room_Type", "Room_No", "Room_Price", "Room_Status", "No_of_Occupancy"}


    Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy " & _
                                    "FROM Room " & _
                                    "WHERE " & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & " LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"

    dbSource = "Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True"

    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True")

        Using com As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            With com
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = strSqlSearch


            End With

            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader

                While dr.Read
                    _isFound = True


                    item = ListViewRoom.Items.Add("Room_Code".ToString)
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Type".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_No".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Price".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Status".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("No_of_Occupancy".ToString))
                End While

                If Not _isFound Then
                    MsgBox("No results found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using
```

[image: This picture is the interface of problem]

Tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, because you're telling it to:

```
item = ListViewRoom.Items.Add("Room_Code".ToString)
```

I suppose that that should be:

```
item = ListViewRoom.Items.Add(dr("Room_Code").ToString)
```

By the way, you've got several other pointless calls to `ToString` too, e.g.

```
item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Type".ToString))
```

What's the point of calling `ToString` on a literal?  Surely it's the field value that you want converted to a `String`:

```
item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Type").ToString())
```

You really should be using a `DataGridView` and simply binding a `DataTable` instead of abusing a `ListView`, which is NOT a grid control.